# Orderby through 2 different tables

Tags: php, mysql

i have two tables one is called `addons` and holds information about different addons, there are a lot of columns but here are the main

```
addon_id  |  addon_name      |  addon_size

1         |  loft conversion |  small
2         |  extension       |  large
```

And i have another one called `addons_count`

```
addon_id  |  addon_count

1         |  5
2         |  6
```

Which holds the number of addons used in the system

The problem is that i have a query already that just outputs the addons through a while loop

```
SELECT * FROM `addons` WHERE addon_size='small' LIMIT {$startpoint_small} , {$limit}
```

However i am trying to make it sort the different addons based on the addon_count, however because they are from 2 different tables how would i do this, such as through an orderby?

Thanks for ay and all help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM 
   addons a , addons_count c 
WHERE
   c.addon_id = a.addon_id
AND
   a.addon_size = 'small'
ORDER BY
   c.addon_count
LIMIT 
   {$startpoint_small} , {$limit}
```

Comment: Hi, sorry i didnt mention the addon_size, it has to be included aswell, thank you for your answer and edit, trying now

Answer (score 1):

You must join your 2 tables:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM addons a, addons_count ac
WHERE a.addon_id=ac.addon_id AND a.addon_size = 'small'
ORDER BY ac.addon_count DESC
LIMIT {$startpoint_small} , {$limit}";
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an INNER JOIN to the query for addons -> addons_count and then sort.